# selected cell position of a jqgrid column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

how can we get the position of selected cell in jqgrid on asp page. I want it to set position of a popup dynamically based on position of cell selected. I am able to fetch selected col id and cell value but not position. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. When you signed up here you were encouraged to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Please do so. It is expected that you have [fully researched this topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) by the time you ask your question here and to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question.

Comment: How do you fetch the column and the value - with which command

Answer (score 0):

the completed datatable that i saw it is [datatables.net](http://datatables.net)

the key table example is:

https://datatables.net/extensions/keytable/examples/initialisation/stateSave

all feature you can imagine it the datatbles.net has it. please do not use another datatable.